# Apparent elimination of overlapping divergences

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization

The integral,

$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2+}}\frac{xy}{1+x+y} \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x$$

possesses an overlapping divergence when $ x \to \infty $ and $ y \to \infty $. However, under a change of variables to polar coordinates,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dr\int_{0}^{2\pi}du \frac{r^{3}\sin(u)\cos(u)}{1+r(\cos(u)+\sin(u))} $$

If we integrate over the angular variables numerically we are left with a sum of one dimensional divergent integrals, $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ar^{3}}{1+br}dr $$

Therefore the overlapping UV divergence is gone. Can be this done to every UV divergent multiple-loop integral?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is exactly. Please note that the $u$ integral doesn't converge in general.

Comment: the integral is still divergent but it is onle a 1-dimensional divergent integral

Comment: No. The $u$ integral is in general divergent, and your expression for the $r$ integral is wrong.

Comment: the integral in 'u' is convergent only the integral over 'r' is here divergent